# 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException' error in laravel

Tags: laravel

So I am trying to update information in database. Everything is fine until duplicate values are given to update in unique field(s). I tried to do this:

```
try{
    if(Employe_info::where('id',$id_to_update)->update($to_update)){
        return redirect()->route('show.employe')->with('success_update', 'Informations were updated successfully.');
    }

}catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
    if($errorCode == 1062){
        return redirect()->route('edit.user')->with('user_exists', 'Email or ID already exists');
    }
}
```

I am trying to catch `QueryException` if duplicate values for unique fields are given. Exactly this code is working fine for my `create` method. But not working for my update method tho it show the same error.
I am getting:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

This is the error when I am trying to catch exception.

This is the location of error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_project_1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php
    if ($request->method() == 'OPTIONS') {
        return (new Route('OPTIONS', $request->path(), function () use ($methods) {
            return new Response('', 200, ['Allow' => implode(',', $methods)]);
        }))->bind($request);
    }

    $this->methodNotAllowed($methods);
}

/**
 * Throw a method not allowed HTTP exception.
 *
 * @param  array  $others
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 */
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

How do I handle this Exception?

Comment: Can you just share whole stack trace? It looks like the issue is in your routes. Update method requires put method if you are using resource routes.

Comment: hmm.. I am actually really new in Laravel and using post method in route cause I am sending form data using post method.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, it should work but make sure you don't pass any data from URL.

Comment: not passing any data through url, passing all data from a form, capturing them using $request->input() everything works if not trying to input duplicate data for unique fields.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of error page?

Comment: Here it is: https://prnt.sc/j023g4

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You need to pass user id with an edit route that is missing that's why you are getting this error. Try something like this `redirect()->route('edit.user',$id_to_update)`.

Comment: Still the same error, guess i fed up something.... Like in my register form it sometimes does not process if mixed (string and int) value is given in an ID field. Tho my input is text and in DB it takes VARCHAR... I am thinking of using Laravel's validate() function rather than catching exception.

Comment: ok try and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Hey, So I have used validate() function for my register form. Everything is working fine for register form, didn't try it in update tho. BTW I was just asking for bit of info.
So in my form I named the ID field as 'employe_id' in my DB the column name is 'employe_id_num' so when I try to validate it obviously won't find the field, I know I can just change the name to whatever is in the DB but just from curiosity I wanted to know if how can I define in validation that form 'employe_id' represents DB 'employe_id_num'?

Comment: You have to write custom validation rules. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: You're welcome...

Answer (score 0):

The `where()->get()` query builder method returns a `Collection` if it finds results, not a singular instance.  If you have the `employee_id` already, just use `find()`.

Change

```
Employe_info::where('id',$id_to_update)
```

to

```
Employe_info::find($id_to_update)
```

Or better yet, use route model binding in your controller.

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::patch('/employe_infos/{employe_info}', 'Employe_infoController@update');

// Employe_infoController.php
public function update(Request $request, Employe_info $employe_info)
{
    $attributes = $request->validate([
        // validation rules here
    ]);

    $employe_info->update($attributes);

    return redirect()->route('show.employe')
        ->with('success_update', 'Informations were updated successfully.');
}
```